# Cannot use line_profiler with Cython

Tags: python, cython, line-profiler

Based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301931/how-to-profile-cython-functions-line-by-line) I was trying to use the [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) with a cythonized function.

On the abovementioned question, the accepted answer gives us an example on how to use it with jupyter notebook.

However, when I try to build the `pyx` file using disutils it doesn't work.

We I plainly try to run the script using

```
kernprof -l -v script.py
```

It only returns the the `Timer unit` elapsed time.

If I try to decorate the function on the cython file using `@profile`, it doesn't compile returning:

```
undeclared name not builtin: profile
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `profile` decorator is injected into the `globals` namespace by `kernprof` and is thus not available at compile time. However, you can [apply the `profile` decorator to a function even after it has been defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741965/decorate-a-function-after-it-is-defined/28742093#28742093). For example, in your `script.py` you could write the following.

```
from cython_module import function_to_be_profiled
# Apply the `profile` decorator
function_to_be_profiled = profile(function_to_be_profiled)

# Use function_to_be_profiled as intended
```

The third line of the snippet will fail if you run the script using standard python, i.e. `python script.py`, because the `profile` decorator is not defined. But it should behave as intended if you run it using `kernprof`.